# Where do I find the function for "kubectl describe <CRD>"?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am studying "kubectl describe" sourcecodes at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/describe/describe.go

However, I still could not figure out how "kubectl decsribe [CRD]" works (as in which function/functions are called).

I am a Go newbie, so would like to get some pointers please. Thanks.

I have read describePod function and understand how it works more or less, but still could not figure out how "kubectl describe [CRD]" works.

Answer (score 0):

`Kubectl describe` command helps to view the entire information about the kubernetes resources like Pods,deployments,services,nodes,jobs etc.

By using **CRD**(Custom Resource Definition) you can do **CRUD** operations like create, update, get and delete commands to access the resources. To use CRD we need to use the **API groups**.

*Example*:

Suppose you specify an **API group** as  **example.crd.com**, which means you can issue the get, list, create, update, and delete commands to access the custom resources under the API group **example.crd.com**.
You can use `kubectl describe crd <crd_name>` to get a description of the CRD.

For more information refer this [official doc](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/kubernetes-custom-resource-definitions/)

Try this similar SO’s  [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58503320) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74182168) for more information